# Method that is called after onResume?

Tags: android, orientation

On orientation change a lot of information is lost in Android, unfortunately, so it has to be rebuilt. I have a calculator type app that uses information stored in the layout from user entered data to calculate, and on orientation change Android restores the layout data for me. The problem is that in onResume I call a method to recalculate the data to reset the display since that would be lost in orientation change. However, it appears that onResume is called before Android restores the data. What should I do?

Comment: Why wouldn't you save the data in a Bundle then read it back in when `onCreate()` is called again?

Comment: I guess I could do that, would of been just easier to do a simple method call to update though.

Comment: Do you simply want a callback after the Views are drawn?

Comment: Might be worth looking into a `Fragment`-based approach to take advantage of the possibility to retain an instance on configuration changes. Alternatively, if you don't have different layout files for portrait/landscape, you could filter out the orientation change so that your `Activity` does not get recreated. I do have to say I usually prefer an approach that's based on some state and update the UI from that (a bit like the 'M' and 'V' in MVC), so I'd only recommend the latter for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, android does not restore the data for you.
After the rotation your activity gets re created.

You should save your data in onSaveInstanceState() and restore it from 
[onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

According to the doc, onResume gets called right after onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: They store any data related to Views, such as EditText values that are currently entered, and restore it after the Activity is recreated.

Comment: They dont. That's one of the reasons why you have onRestore / onSave instancestate methods.

Comment: I assure you, they do. I have no methods setup to save/restore my data and on orientation change any user input data from Spinners or EditTexts, etc is still there.